# Neverending while-loop in C++ that is to end when an input string == no?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

I am trying to write a code that sums two input integers, and keeps on adding an integer for as long as the user wishes to do so, and if the user wants to exit simply writes "no". This does not work, however. When you write "no" it just goes crazy and adds and subtracts seemingly random numbers. My main function simply runs `inputIntegersUsingLoopAndPrintSum()`

```
void inputIntegersUsingLoopAndPrintSum() {
    int input;
    string answer;

    int sum = inputIntegersAndPrintSum();

    cout << "do you wish to continue? if you don't; write no\n";
    getline(cin, answer); //If you wish to continue
    while (answer != "no") {
        input = inputInteger();
        sum = sum + input;
        cout << "new sum is: " << sum << "\n";
        cout << "do you wish to continue? if you don't; write no\n";
        getline(cin, answer);   
    }


    int inputInteger() {
       int tall;
       cout << "Skriv inn et tall: "; 
       cin >> tall;
       return tall;

       int inputIntegersAndPrintSum() {
           int input1, input2, sum;
           input1 = inputInteger(); //bruker den som returnere en verdi
           input2 = inputInteger();

           sum = input1 + input2;
           cout << "Summen av tallene: " << sum << "\n";
           return sum;
       }
```

Comment: Don't mix `getline` and `>>`. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: have you tried to print `answer` always the loop runs? Write something like `while(answer != "no"){ cout<<answer<<endl; ...` and check what you are getting.

Comment: probably when you use `cin` in the method `inputInteger()` it may cause some bug when you call `getline` on `answer`

Comment: It simply worked replacing the getlines I had been using. The first time I did that it did not compile, but after restarting visual it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking this... check out this short program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char choice = ' ';
    unsigned value = 0;
    unsigned temp = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter a value to be added to." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> value;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter another value." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> temp;

        value += temp;

        std::cout << value << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Would you like to continue (Y/N)?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;

    } while ( choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only difference here is it will continue as long as the user presses `Y` or `y` anything else will evaluate to false including `N` or `n` since I'm only getting a single character. This can be expanded to accept and check for strings or char arrays and it is just a matter of adjusting the conditionals in the while loop expression or statement.